# Convert Reactive Cocoa Code to RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, reactive-cocoa

For this code

```
  fileprivate let nameChangedProperty = MutableProperty("")
  public func nameChanged(_ name: String) {
    self.nameChangedProperty.value = name
  }
```

What I did

```
fileprivate let nameChangedProperty = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")
  public func nameChanged(_ name: String) {
    self.nameChangedProperty.accept(name)
}
```

But confused about

```
    public init() {
    let initialText = self.viewDidLoadProperty.signal.mapConst("")
    let name = Signal.merge(
      self.nameChangedProperty.signal,
      initialText
    )
}
```

here, for first line, I did

```
let initialToken = self.viewDidLoadProperty.asObservable().map { _ in "" }
```

but no idea abut merge signal ....

If some theory concepts are given, is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Observable](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/RxSwift/2.4/Classes/Observable.html) has static method [merge](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/RxSwift/2.4/Protocols/ObservableType.html#/s:Fe7RxSwiftRxS_14ObservableTypewx1ES_25ObservableConvertibleTyperS0_5mergeFT_GCS_10ObservableWxS1_1E__) method. You could make the following changes to your code to create name observable.

```
let initialText = rx.sentMessage(#selector(MyViewController.viewDidLoad)).map { _ in "" }
let name = Observable.merge(initialText, nameChangedProperty.asObservable())
```